# How to enter the Drop Down List Id into the sqlite database from in Flex mobile application for playbook?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4.5, flexbuilder

Please do some help , I am not able to enter the Database Id into the Sqlite database in my flex mobile application. Below is my Code:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

            [Bindable]public var acItem : ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(
                [   {ItemName:'ABC',data:0},
                    {ItemName:'XYZ',data:1},
                    {ItemName:'PQR',data:2},

                ]);
            protected function dropdown_changeHandler(e:IndexChangeEvent):void
                {

                selection = e.newIndex;

                }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:DropDownList id="dropdown" width="150" height="61.35" change="dropdown_changeHandler(event)"
                dataProvider="{acItem}" fontSize="16" labelField="ItemName"
                prompt="SelectDatabase"
                x.landscape="492" y.landscape="380" width.landscape="215"
                height.landscape="31.35"
                x.portrait="243" y.portrait="568" width.portrait="215" height.portrait="31.35">

</s:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Above Code Is Fully Correct . 
When I pass the value of the Drop down String in to the database that time I used the ","+"dropdown.Id+"," but Its wrong . Than I try once again or use the ","+"dropdown.selectedIndex"+"," It works properly.

So If any one Using the sqlite so use the above decleration .
Thanks,
Vinod